# JQM pageinit event not firing

Tags: events, jquery-mobile

I am developing a web application using JQM. On one page I have this script:

```
$('#testpage').on('pageinit', function () {
  alert('testpage pageinit event fired');
});
```

where the page id = testpage.

According to the JQM documentation, this event should fire when the page is loaded when it is visited for the first time but this is not happening for me.

When I go directly to the page I see the alert but if I visit other pages first and then go to the page, I don't see the alert leading me to believe the event is not firing at all.

I also tried the below syntax:

```
 $(document).on('pageinit', '#testpage', function () {
   alert('testpage pageinit event fired');
 });
```

and the exact same thing happens.

This is one of the most basic things to be able to do in JQM and it fails.  Please tell me why this is not working the way it is documented.

Comment: where are you placing your script? inside #testpage? or in a separate js file?

Comment: I am placing it inside testpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, which is that script code on an earlier page was breaking the script code on the page where I was trying to capture the pageinit event.  When I removed that bad script, this started working.  So this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Why binding pageinit to page didnt work

The reason this happens is because at the time you're binding the `pageinit` to `testPage`, its not yet in the DOM. So its not working. **You must be having this bit of code in `<head/>` which will load before your `<body/>` section loads, where your `testPage` lies.** That's why it fails. So how do you make it work? Add this :

```
$('#testpage').on('pageinit', function () {
  alert('testpage pageinit event fired');
});
```

to the **end** of the  `<body>` section of your HTML. So everything will be loaded, and then your page would be bound to its `pageinit` event. Here's how your code will look like :

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="testPage"></div>
  <script>
    $("#testPage").on("pageinit", function() {
       alert("pageinit fires- this is in body.");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Here's a demo : http://jsbin.com/umorof/1/edit

## Why binding pageinit to document works

The reason why binding your `pageinit` works in this case is because `document` will be present the instance your page is called. So, the `pageinit` is administered to `testPage` by **event delegation**. When the `testPage` is loading for the first time, the `document` triggers the `pageinit` event of the `testPage`.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: No, the script was in the body but I believe I found the issue (or at least what made it work).  I am developing in ASP.Net MVC 4 and in the default layout file it puts the rendering of jquery and jquery mobile script at the end of the body.  What this means is that any script in the individual pages gets rendered before jquery and jquery mobile get loaded.  I discovered this by viewing the source of the rendered page.  I moved the loading of the jquery and jquery mobile to the end of the head section and then the pageinit event on the testpage fired as it should have.

Comment: While the pageinit is firing on the test screen, it is not firing on a different screen and I cannot figure out why.